# Want to append tooltip content in <li> element

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>This is first point</li>
    <li>This is second point <a href="http://" title="This is more tooltip">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to append the anchor tags title text within the `li` element using jquery so that I will get plain text with no hyperlinks.

For example, after processing the `li` element will be

```
<li>This is second point This is more tooltip</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it (comments in code to explain what is happening):

```js
$('li').each(function() {  // loop through each li - you can change this selector to match your needs
  var li = $(this),
      anchors = li.find('a'); // in case there are multiple anchors?
  
  anchors.each(function() {
    var anchor = $(this),
        title = anchor.attr('title');
    
    if (typeof title !== typeof undefined && title !== false) { // do this if so only if the title attribute exists do you remove the anchor
      anchor.after(title);  // place the title after the link so it keeps it's place in the li (in case there is text after the link).  If you just want the text at the end of the li use li.append(title);
      anchor.detach();   // remove the anchor - move this to after the if statement if you want to remove the anchor and it's text regardless of whether or not it has a title.  If you want to keep the text in the anchor, just remove this line altogether
    }
  });
  
  // li.text(li.text()); // remove all other html within li (optional)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>This is first point</li>
    <li><strong>This is second point</strong> <a href="http://" title="This is more tooltip">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. This worked like a charm for my requirement.

Comment: May I know why it removes the other formatting in li element like text bold?

Comment: That's the line at the end that is optional:  `li.text(li.text()); // remove all other html within li (optional)`

Comment: It is happening even that line is commented.

Comment: It shouldn't do - see above edit (unless your bold text is within the anchor?).  Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the html you are using so I can see what is being stripped out

Comment: I need customised string of li element - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sisodeB/vt5usfy3/1/)

Comment: Ok, so you should use `li.html()` if you want to keep the html - https://jsfiddle.net/vt5usfy3/2/

Answer (score 0):

This gives you exactly what you want.  Adjust to be more simplistic if you add IDs to your elements.

```
var text = $("ul li:last a").attr("title");
$("ul li:last a").remove();

text = $("ul li:last").text() + text;
$("ul li:last").text(text);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swu11dLb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  title:

```
<li id="yourElementId">example</li>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('yourElementId').title = 'your new title';
```